# Formatting data in correct format for HighCharts mvc asp.net

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, highcharts

Would you like some help I am not able to leave the format to be able to generate a graph using highchart,

Do the following query in the database:

```
var query = (from ir in db.IRR1235
                                 where ir.cod_levantamento_id == idCodLev
                                 select ir);


                    foreach (var item in query)
                    {
                        object[] values = new object[2];
                        values[0] = Convert.ToDecimal(item.inicial);
                        values[1] = Convert.ToDecimal(item.ir);
                        dataResult.Add(values);


                    }
```

return the result to json

```
 return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

But the graph is just like this,

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't show us how you are calling `Highcharts` (and in the future, please provide enough code to reproduce your problem), but looking at what you've given us, your JSON would produce something like this:

```
var jsonData = [[0,0],[1,10],[2,20],[3,30],[4,40],[5,50],[6,60],[7,70],[8,80],[9,90]];
```

If you called `Highcharts` like this:

```
$('#container').highcharts({
    series: jsonData
});
```

It would produce a broken plot like you show in your image.

If you called highcharts like this though:

```
    $('#container').highcharts({
        series: [{data: jsonData}]
    });
```

You'd get a single data series plotted correctly.

Comment: @Mark: Please help me on my [question here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27983248/need-help-in-plotting-a-chart-using-highcharts-in-angularjs)